# Passing Data To Container View From Parent View

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uicontainerview

So I've seen some examples of this and have tried implementing them but can't seem to get it to work. I have Two VCs (both marked as VC1 in my photo) which go to a second view controller (VC2 in photo). VC2 has a container view. I pass data from a property on VC1 to a property on VC2 and then I need to pass that data from V2 to a property on container view. Based on using some NSLogs it appears that the prepare for segue for my embedded segue that goes from VC2 to my container view is firing off before the property on VC2 is being set by the data passed by VC1, which means no data is being passed to my container view. Any way to get around this? Thanks in advance.

This is my prepareForSegue in VC2:

my container view is WineryPhotosCVC. I'm trying to set WineryPhotosCVC's winery property with VC2s winery property. VC2s winery property is not being set by VC1 before the prepareForSegue to my container view is called.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if ([segue.identifier isEqual: @"containerViewSegue"]) {
    WineryPhotosCVC *wineryPhotosCVC = segue.destinationViewController;
    wineryPhotosCVC.winery = _winery;
   }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a reference to the container view to modify and access it. So add that and then in your `viewWillAppear` (which happens after the prepareForSegue, passes the data to VC2) of VC2, you just set the property of the container either directly or using a function on the container VC e.g. `configure(someDataStructure: DataStructure)`

Comment: I tried adding a reference to my container view and added it to viewWillAppear but the data still won't pass. This was my code in the viewWillAppear of VC2: `wineryPhotosCVC.winery = self.winery;` Can you explain further on what you mean by setting a function in the container view? Thanks

Comment: That should work. Set a breakpoint and inspect winery when you set it. Also, even if you set it, what do you want to do with it in the containerview? Check the delegate methods for the container view when it becomes visible and see if it has the winery data available.

Comment: GOT IT! thanks for the help. The problem was my reference to my container view controller. I ended up getting the reference by doing `    WineryPhotosCVC *wineryPhotosCVC = self.childViewControllers[0];`. Then I did 'wineryPhotosCVC.winery = self.winery;' the Winery property has an id that I needed to pass to a network call made in my container view to grab photos from Foursquare. I appreciate all your help.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You can save a reference in VC2 for Container view and pass the data when it comes in VC2 in didSet method maybe.

Comment: Can you give an example because I tried doing it this way: `-(void)setWinery:(Winery *)winery {
    _winery = winery;
    self.wineryPhotosCollectionViewController.winery = winery;
}` and then called it in my view will appear. I also tried doing         `wineryPhotosCVC.winery = self.winery;` in my VC2 viewWillAppear but that didn't work. `wineryPhotosCVC` is my container view.